# Bike accessory: what is this for?

Tags: accessories

I’ve been given this bike since it wasn’t used. It has this thing attached to the frame on the rear wheel. Does anyone know what it is for?[image: accessory]

Comment: How old is the bike? That looks like a *really* old rear light clamp, for lights that take a couple of D-cell batteries (i.e. [this sort of thing](http://www.useddudley.co.uk/classified-ad/Vintage-ever-ready-bike-lights-_23898674) )

Comment: @Diado Please don't post answers as comments.

Comment: Not sure how old, is there a way to find out? It does look old but is in good condition so I’m happy with it!

Comment: @DavidRicherby As I said, it *looks* like - doesn't mean it is, it could be for a large number of things, hence it only warranting a comment.

Comment: @Diado If you think your answer might be wrong, it's even more important to post it as an answer. If you post it as a comment, you bypass the site's biggest quality-control mechanism by only allowing up-votes.

Comment: @DavidRicherby It was an exploratory comment asking for more information and offering a possibility in passing. You've gone ahead and posted it as an answer anyway, so the issue is moot.

Comment: I wonder why the question doesn’t get any [up]votes...

Comment: @Diado the issue isn’t moot because answers don’t go in comments. David’s explanation is good and fair.

Comment: @Neeku some questions attract more upvotes because people find them particularly interesting or relevant to their own experiences. But it’s a good question, well written and with a good photograph, I’ll upvote. Other times, a quick and accurate answer is the reward for a well-written question. Better that than people up voting q but not knowing the answer!

Comment: @Swifty Indeed, exploratory comments go in comments. Things such as asking for further information, giving suggestions on what something *looks* like and could possibly be depending on context and further information, but equally might well not be when the further information is provided. Things that *aren't* answers, but passing, you know, *comments*, whilst awaiting further information. Still moot, "answer" has been posted.

Comment: @Diado don’t worry, not the first not the last, it seems to happen a lot atm and we need to improve it. David explained clearly and concisely the value of being able to upvote and downvote on possible answers and suggestions. Earlier, I realised I’d done the same thing elsewhere and so made an answer out of my comment, then deleted the comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bracket for holding an old style light like these

[image]

<sup>Photo from Amazon</sup>

Comment: I had a set of those in the 90's. I mostly remember the pathetic light output.

Comment: Isn’t what I’ve got too huge compared to these ones? That must have been a massive light? :-/

Comment: @Neeku They’re huge. The reflector/light part is 7-8 cm across and they take C type batteries or even larger. This is from the days before halogen bulbs and LEDs.